# Dockerfileを使ってのgit cloneが出来ない。Using Cacheは試しています。

Tags: command-line

dockerfileを使って、docker上にNEologdをインストールしようとしています。

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd.git
```

上記コマンドを使いインストールして、エラーは出ずにcloningは完了するのですが、Dockerを見てみると指定したディレクトリに mecab-ipadic-neologdのディレクトリがありません。なので後の

```
RUN .bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
```

で

```
/bin/sh: .bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd: No such file or directory
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。こういう状況を解決された経験がある方、もしくは知識がある方アドバイス頂けませんでしょうか？

mecab-NEologdの箇所のみ追記致します。

```
RUN yum -y install xz

RUN yum -y install patch
RUN yum -y install file

WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic

RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd.git

WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd/

RUN .bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
```

cloningは下記の通り表示されているので出来ていると思うのですが。

```
Step 59/67 : RUN yum -y install xz
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e36c255a6c4f
Step 60/67 : RUN yum -y install patch
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0d508606bef7
Step 61/67 : RUN yum -y install file
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d0f183a946e
Step 62/67 : RUN echo done!
 ---> Running in 2aad4678689a
done!
Removing intermediate container 2aad4678689a
 ---> 1d6e5c5b2ad3
Step 63/67 : WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic
Removing intermediate container 975276dcd91e
 ---> ababd2f4b24a
Step 64/67 : RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd.git
 ---> Running in a4ce121470f9
Cloning into 'mecab-ipadic-neologd'...
Removing intermediate container a4ce121470f9
 ---> 751d96787e7d
Step 65/67 : WORKDIR /usr/local/lib/mecab/dic/mecab-ipadic-neologd/
Removing intermediate container 4a6c62a8abcc
 ---> 68230fdc8224
Step 66/67 : RUN .bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a
 ---> Running in e4fd4d4729db
/bin/sh: .bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 念のため、Dockerfile全体を質問文に追記してもらうことは可能ですか？また、「cloningは完了する」と判断したbuild実行時のメッセージなどもあるとよいかもしれません。

Comment: ``` RUN yum -y install xz```  ```RUN yum -y install patch```

Comment: `.bin` は `./bin` ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 投稿に含まれるソースコードや、整形済みのテキストは[選択した上で `{}` ボタンをクリック](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにできます。インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。また、失敗したコメントは削除できます。次回、必要になりましたら参考にして下さい。

Comment: mjy ご指摘の通りでした。お陰様で解決出来ました。ありがとうございます！！